# How can i stop receiving irrelevant disk_usage metrics while using CloudWatchAgent?

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs, amazon-cloudwatch-metrics

Following is the config.json that I'm using

```
{
    "agent": {
        "metrics_collection_interval": 300,
        "run_as_user": "root"
    },
    "metrics": {
        "append_dimensions": {
            "AutoScalingGroupName": "${aws:AutoScalingGroupName}",
            "ImageId": "${aws:ImageId}",
            "InstanceId": "${aws:InstanceId}",
            "InstanceType": "${aws:InstanceType}"
        },
        "metrics_collected": {
            "disk": {
                "measurement": [
                    "used_percent"
                ],
                "metrics_collection_interval": 300,
                "resources": [
                    "/"
                ]
            },
            "mem": {
                "measurement": [
                    "mem_used_percent"
                ],
                "metrics_collection_interval": 300
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But using this configuration I am receiving many metrics which i dont need, pasting a sample pic below.

[image: AWS CloudWatchAgent Metrics]

I just need the disk_used_percent metric for **device**: rootfs and **path**: /

Comment: Have same curious. Though I think you can not.